# Prevent unwanted button click when pressing "enter"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two textboxes each having a button next to it, when the user clicks enter in one of the textboxes the button next to it should be clicked (`onkeydown` javascript code). The problem is that when the user clicks Enter the button "`btnSource_Type`" is clicked regardless of which textbox has focus.

I tried removing the "`onkeydown`" event from the `txtSource_Type` textbox and still the `BtnSource_Type` is clicked.

How can I only let the specified button to be clicked and not have the first button in page be clicked ?

```
<tr>
    <td width="20%"> Source Type</td>
    <td width="80%">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSource_Type" runat="Server" Text='<%# Bind("Source_Type_Name") %>' Width="90%"  onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('MainContent_frmArticle_Source_btnSource_TypeGridView').click();" CssClass="textbox" style=" font-family: 'Segoe UI',Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif !important; font-size: small  !important;font-weight: normal !important;" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSource_Type" OnClientClick=" alert('Source Btn Clicked');" OnClick="btnSource_TypeClick" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/find1.png" Width="3%"   />

    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="20%"> Author Name</td>
    <td width="80%">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAuthor" runat="Server" Text='<%# Bind("Author_Name") %>' Width="90%" CssClass="textbox" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('MainContent_frmArticle_Source_btnAuthor').click();" style=" font-family: 'Segoe UI',Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif !important; font-size: small  !important;font-weight: normal !important;"  />

        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAuthor" OnClick="btnAuthor_Click" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/find1.png" Width="3%"   />

    </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hope this code helps you: 

$('#txtSource_Type').bind("keyup keypress", function(e) { 
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 

      if (code  == 13) {                 
             $('#btnSource_Type').click(function(e) { 
             perform_task(); 
        } 
      }
    });
```

similarly,

```
$('#txtAuthor').bind("keyup keypress", function(e) { 
          var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 

          if (code  == 13) {                 
                 $('#btnAuthor').click(function(e) { 
                 perform_task(); 
            } 
          }
        });
```